# Bridging the gap between OpenGL and the Operating System

Tags: c++, opengl, cross-platform

I'm interested in getting into some Indie Game Development in C++, and I would like to use OpenGL 3+ to do so. The main problem I am facing right now is deciding how to bridge the gap between OpenGL and the operating system, as I intend to do all my development across Windows, Linux, and Mac. Should I write my own top layer, using platform specific code for window management, I/O, ect.? Should I use a cross platform library such as SDL, or FreeGLUT? Will these sacrifice performance?

As a side note, I haven't done much Linux programming.
Is there a tutorial on how to use the X Window Server with OpenGL?

Comment: I can easily compile and run my engine on Windows, OS X and Linux. Using GLFW, GLEW, GLM, OpenGL 3.2 core (with some 3.3 extensions because of OS X limitations), BASS or FMOD for sound. Just don't do anything platform specific. OS X is normally behaving well, but Linux can be a chore because of driver bugs. Make sure you actually have a mac and linux box to test things as you go. It requires some extra effort.

Comment: Another vote here for the GLFW/GLEW/GLM combo. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) (C++ SDL), but FreeGLUT and Allegro are both also good. They provide basic window creation, input handling, and more (depending on what you choose). I don't think that any of them are innately cross-platform though (They have different versions for Windows, Mac, Linux).

In terms of performance, SFML's window package alone (creating a window and setting up an openGL context) doesn't slow anything down. I've had performance issues when using it's Graphics package though.

Can't help you on the linux programming myself, but a quick google search got me results like [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Programming_OpenGL_in_Linux%3a_GLX_and_Xlib).

Answer (score 0):

> Should I write my own top layer, using platform specific code for window management, I/O, ect.?

No. If you have no experience with this you should not do it.

> Should I use a cross platform library such as SDL, or FreeGLUT?

Definitely.

> Will these sacrifice performance?

No. It doesn't matter to the OpenGL implementation which way the window and the context have been created with. It looks all the same to the OpenGL implementation.

> X Window Server with OpenGL?

FTB/Fungus did post a simplemost OpenGL on X11 example years ago. I expanded it a little some time ago to support transparent window compositing. Of course this is not very portable (in the sense of using it without X11, you can still port it to Windows and use it on a X11 server running on Windows).

https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/tree/master/samples/OpenGL/x11argb_opengl